# stringValue in touchXML when saved is messed up

Tags: ios, touchxml

```
NSLog(@"Status: %@", [[[xmlElement elementsForName:@"status"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue]);
NSString *val = [[[xmlElement elementsForName:@"status"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
NSLog(@"Status: %@", val);
```

the log shows
2011-07-02 16:06:45.014 Revistero[949:207] Status: error
2011-07-02 16:06:45.014 Revistero[949:207] Status: error

However this doesn't work
  if (val == @"error")
Any suggestion?

Comment: Please don't change answered questions to ask new questions.  Accept the answer, then ask a new question separately.

Comment: You changed the question. Not cool. Just to be clear... you actually implemented Jim's answer in your code above and then tried to turn this into a new question. (Which isn't clear BTW.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%s` is the format specifier for plain old C strings.  `NSString`s are Objective C objects, you can use the `%@` format specifier to log them.